# Python Merge Sort Recursive

Tags: python, recursion, mergesort

I am having issues regarding my merge_sort function, specifically performing recursive sorting the right sub-list.

The hint that was given for this assignment was:

```
# if min_ < max_
# calculate mid ((min + max) // 2)
#recursively sort left sub-list
# recursively sort right sub-list
# merge sorted sub-lists

# merge_sort function
"""
:param unsorted_list: The list to be sorted
:param min_: The minimum index to sort from the given list
:param max_: The maximum index to sort from the given list
Returns nothing, the original list is modified so no copy is needed
"""
```

Merge_sort Function

```
def merge_sort(unsorted_list, min_, max_):
    mid_ = (min_ + max_) // 2
    if min_ < max_:
        merge_sort(unsorted_list, min_, mid_)
        merge(unsorted_list, min_, mid_)
        return merge_sort(unsorted_list, mid_ + 1, max_)
    merge(unsorted_list, mid_ + 1, max_)

test_list = [4, 12, 20, 1, 2, 17, 3, 11, 18, 1]

merge_sort(test_list, 0, len(test_list) - 1)
```

Testing my function with the test list above yields:

```
[1, 2, 4, 12, 20, 17, 3, 11, 18, 1]
```

which indicates that the left sublist is working but not the right sublist.

What the expected output should return:

```
[1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 11, 12, 17, 18, 20]
```

My code for merge function:

```
def merge(unsorted_list, min_, max_):
    # mid position = start of second sub-list
    mid = ((min_ + max_) // 2) + 1

    position1 = min_
    position2 = mid
    position3 = 0

    temp = []
    stop = False
    while stop == False and position2 < len(unsorted_list) and position1 < mid:
        if unsorted_list[position1] <= unsorted_list[position2]:
            temp.append(unsorted_list[position1])
            position1 += 1
            position3 += 1
        else:
            temp.append(unsorted_list[position2])
            position2 += 1
            position3 += 1

        if position1 >= position2:
            for k in range(position1, mid + 1):
                temp.append(unsorted_list[k])
                position2 += 1
                position3 += 1
            stop = True
            if position3 == len(unsorted_list):# temp
                for i in range(len(temp)):
                    unsorted_list[min_] = temp[i]
                    min_ += 1
        elif position2 > max_:
            for k in range(position1, mid):
                temp.append(unsorted_list[k])
                position3 += 1
            stop = True
            if position3 == len(unsorted_list):# temp
                for i in range(len(temp)):
                    unsorted_list[min_] = temp[i]
                    min_ += 1

    if position3 != len(unsorted_list):
        for k in range(position2, len(unsorted_list)):
                temp.append(unsorted_list[k])
                position3 += 1
        if position3 > max_ and position3 == len(temp):
            for i in range(len(temp)):
                unsorted_list[min_] = temp[i]
                min_ += 1
```

Comment: can you show the code for your `merge()` function?

Comment: just added the merge() function at the bottom.

Comment: Looking at merge, I see the main loop depends on len(unsorted_list), but it is supposed to be working on a subproblem from min_ to max_, not the whole list.

Comment: Your merge_sort function does not follow the instructions. I'm not sure what's going on in merge, but you might want to start over on that and test it by itself. But that's another issue. This may help: http://penguin.ewu.edu/cscd300/Topic/AdvSorting/MergeSorts/InPlace.html